# What is the difference between Moen Moentrol 3510/3520 and 3550/3570?

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve

I'm trying to pick out a new valve for my shower, and I'm pretty set on a Moentrol.  Moen produces four differnet models:

- Two 1/2" IPS Models: 3510 and 3550
- Two 1/2" CC Models: 3520 and 3570

Their spec sheets are available at:

- [3510 and 3520](http://www.moen.com/shared/docs/product-specifications/3510sp.pdf)
- [3550 and 3570](http://pro.moen.com/shared/docs/product-specifications/3570sp.pdf)

The only differences that I see in the specs are "integral checks" compared to "integral check stops"

Can someone please enlighten me on the differences between the 3510/3520 line and the 3550/3570 line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3570 has shut off valves on the valve itself. Allows you to swap out 1225 cartridge without shutting off water to house

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the connection to the valve. The 3520 is a copper connection that needs to be sweat together. The 3510 is a threaded connection